# Conditional rendering did not protect from rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this snippet of code:

```
document.lines && (<div>
                    <h4>Title1</h4>
                    {
                        document.lines
                            .concat(["end"])
                            .filter(Boolean)
                            .map((line, i) =>
                                <p key={i}>{line}</p>
                            )
                    }
                </div>)
```

Everything works great when `document.lines` is valid. In one of my test, I run with a falsy value. I thought that `document.lines &&` will protect me but no. I face this typescript error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

In angular world I would have write `<div *ngIf="document.lines">` and in vue world I would have write `<div v-if="document.lines">`. I think I am missing something with react.

Why my guard did not protect me? How can I change my code to avoid the problem?

Comment: empty array, objects etc are not falsy. It would be hard to say till u give console log of document.lines

Comment: Strange, it should have protected you. Are you sure an error points to that line and not some other concat? Can you create a reduced test case that shows the error?

Comment: @GlebKost I will look to create a proper [mcve] with stackblitz.

Comment: @GlebKost it is always easier like this. It help me find what I was missing. I was able to answer. Thank you

Comment: @aloisdg Great! Happened to me a lot of times ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you wrap your code inside `{ ... }`? Whithout them, `document.lines &&` is going to be read by react as plain html ([demo of this behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-whyr6z?file=index.js)).

Try this:

```
{
    document.lines && <div>
                    <h4>Title1</h4>
                    {
                        document.lines
                            .concat(["end"])
                            .filter(Boolean)
                            .map((line, i) =>
                                <p key={i}>{line}</p>
                            )
                    }
                </div>
}
```

Here is a [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cmnecm?file=index.js) made with stackblitz. (You can set lines to undefined to show that the falsy case is handled properly).

Answer (score 1):

In this way your guard just checks if `document.lines` exists, but not if it is an array.

Change your guard to:

`Array.isArray(document.lines) && ...`

Comment: Since the error says `'concat' of undefined` it seems to me, it has nothing to do with it being or not being an array.

Comment: Nope. Tried without success.

Comment: @GlebKost actually you are right. @aloisdg are you sure that you don't use anywhere else this `document.lines.concat`?